# What does the __VIEWSTATE hold?

Tags: asp.net, forms, viewstate, hidden-field

I'm sorry for maybe making such a basic question but in ASP.NET websites what does the __VIEWSTATE input field represent?

Also, is there any way to compute it's value (based on the values of other form fields)?

#### EDIT

I understand that __VIEWSTATE, as the name suggests, maintains the values of form field values in webpages however what I'm interested in knowing is how this state (the string) is generated. If I base64_decode any __VIEWSTATE string all I see is a bunch of cryptic HTML.

Is there any way to better understand what exactly is being encoded? I've searched on past questions and I've found some tools that can do this [like this one](http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/fritz/archive/2007/07/17/updated-viewstate-decoder.aspx), but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work.

The reason I'm asking this is because I've access to a web service API that gives me most of the values I need to work with. However I also need an additional field that is only available on the last stage of the form. I already contacted the web service provider but unfortunately and they're not going to update their API so soon. I was hoping I could prefill the form initial values using the web service data and then calculate the __VIEWSTATE to access the last field that shows up on the last stage of the form, it would make the whole process a lot faster.

Not sure if I made myself clear enough though...

Comment: Answers to this question is a list of links :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Paul Wilson has a very good article: [ViewState: All You Wanted to Know](http://aspalliance.com/articleViewer.aspx?aId=135&pId=)

VIEWSTATE can be deserialized with the [LosFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.losformatter.aspx) class.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search answers the question:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx

First sentence:

> Microsoft® ASP.NET view state, in a
>   nutshell, is the technique used by an
>   ASP.NET Web page to persist changes to
>   the state of a Web Form across
>   postbacks.

Comment: Search google?  Communist!  90% of this site would go away if people started doing that.  :)

Comment: +1, and it was funny, because it's true... (read it imitating Sheldon Cooper's voice)

Comment: @John Lockwood and @felideon 1 plus for both of you

Comment: The funny thing is 90% of SO's traffic comes from Google. I think Jeff Atwood mentioned it in one of the podcasts.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to understand it well, see [Dave Reed's article about ViewState](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Do take a look at the biter script posted at http://forums.techarena.in/windows-software/1329157.htm.

That script shows how to set up and use __ViewState and other .NET variables.

That script logs into a .NET site, and gets stock values, without going thru a browser. Instead of user doing it manually, the script does it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by compute it's value?

Assume that it is a compressed (actually Base64 encoded) pair of your form fields/values in text form, which gets serialized into server side objects for you to work with.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of doing this in Razor is putting this on a view:

```
@{
    throw new Exception();
}
```