# What is viewstate and what is its use?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the __VIEWSTATE hold?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350216/what-does-the-viewstate-hold)

I am new to ASP.NET.I want to know about viewstate in detail.

although this is so simple but i am unable to understand it.

So please tell that what is viewstate and what is its use?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What viewstate? This view state? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a link Which explain it. [ASP .NET Maintaining the ViewState](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_viewstate.asp)

> When a form is submitted in ASP .NET,
>   the form reappears in the browser
>   window together with all form values.
>   How come? This is because ASP .NET
>   maintains your ViewState. The
>   ViewState indicates the status of the
>   page when submitted to the server. The
>   status is defined through a hidden
>   field placed on each page with a  control.