# What is this strange obfuscated-looking HTML code i see in the ASPX page I'm studying?

Tags: html, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the __VIEWSTATE hold?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350216/what-does-the-viewstate-hold)

I'm studying the code for my company's website, and I see the following:

[image]

Basically, the code is this:

```
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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....... ETC... ETC. ... VURrv" />
</div>
```

Why would anyone do this? Does it have anything to do with obfuscation?

Comment: Have you tried googling for "View State"? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: related: [What does the \_\_VIEWSTATE hold?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350216/what-does-the-viewstate-hold)

Comment: @Jimmy - I will now, ok thank

Comment: @lc.  Nope. OP is asking also about `__EVENTTARGET` and `__EVENTARGUMENT`

Comment: For reference - and because this was part of your question - this data is Base64 encoded, both to avoid encoding issues that would arise attempting to store the data in plain text and to allow the hashing the data using a unique server machine key to avoid client side tampering with data. The ViewState is transferred back and forth with every postback and it looks like the website has a lot, this will slow performance. If you're using .NET 4 then you might want to look at [ViewStateMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.ui.control.viewstatemode(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These hidden fields hold the event and view state data to support server side work in web forms.

[TRULY Undstanding ViewState](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx) would start you on the way - it is a rather old article by now, but very good regardless. The two other hidden fields use to manage server side events.

I also suggest reading [Understanding the JavaScript __doPostBack Function](http://aspalliance.com/articleViewer.aspx?aId=895&pId=-1).